# Prefix permission name dynamically in AndroidManifest to avoid duplicate conflicts

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an Android Library, in its manifest there are a set of permissions declared and used. This library needs to be bundled with different apps. When installing, it says duplicate permission declared across apps. The apps would be of different signature.

In order to use the same permission across apps, can we prefix the permission name in the library with packageName (like `${applicationId}`)?

When I try to prefix permissions with `${applicationId}`, it gets substituted with the library's packageName. Is there a way to replace it in the top level apk or any other way out?